# P4PYTHON : 'str' object has no attribute '_description'

Tags: python-2.7

from P4 import P4, P4Exception

```
p4 = P4()

p4.connect()

change = p4.fetch_change()

change._description = "My changelist\nSubmitted from P4Python\n"
```

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_description'

how can i fix this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Problem, I fixed it.I was using an older version of P4PYTHON module